# Allow UI to process all messages coming from IProgress<T>

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await

I wanted to create a helper method that could take a delegate and run it on a background thread, while showing the progress of the method in a UI. The UI shows a non-marquee progress bar with cancel button and is modal; this is really a synchronous operation but I want to keep the UI responsive and show the progress of the operation.

The UI should open, run the delegate, and then close. The problem is that sometimes the UI will close before all progress reports have been 'processed' i.e. the progress bar does not always get to 100% before the UI closes.

Here is the code:

```
public static void Execute(Action<IProgress<ProgressInfo>> action, IWin32Window parent)
{
    using (var progressDialog = new ProgressDialog())
    {
        progressDialog.Shown += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            ProgressDialog dialog = (ProgressDialog)sender;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                action(dialog.Progress);

                if (!dialog.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // this is a workaround: we need time for the UI to update and show 100% progress before closing
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }, dialog.CancellationToken);

            dialog.Close();
        };

        progressDialog.ShowDialog(parent);
    }
}
```

The workaround is simply to wait a little while before closing the dialog to give the UI thread a chance to process the messages updating the progress bar before closing.

Is there a better (non-workaround) way to do this?

Comment: Maybe an Application.DoEvents() right before the dialog.Close() will do the trick. I'm not sure so just a comment.

Comment: ProgressBar is animated in later Windows versions, it smoothly interpolates intermediate values.  That inevitably causes a delay, it can only interpolate by always being late.  So you never visibly make it to 100.  A hack is to intentionally move it backwards, that is not interpolated.  Still, that gets you to 99, not 100.  There is no option to turn interpolation off, other than disabling the VisualStyle, you won't enjoy that.  Only other thing you can do is keep it intentionally visible for longer than necessary.

Comment: Don't use Thread.Sleep but Task.Delay